# Get newest files from directory (with Child-Items) using PowerShell

Tags: command-line, powershell

### Intention/Task

Retrieve the newest file from a nested directory structure. Let's assume the following given directory structure:

```
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\    
                            foo.example.com\
                                            2014\cert-10457879297372006618810300677.pem
                                            2016\cert-13677147326148109482722985339.pem
                                            2019\cert-12284327752958698998181242513.pem
                                            2020\cert-12335167671983512419735879508.pem
                                            2021\cert-12482084320823734707339770201.pem
                            bar.example.com\
                                            2017\cert-10767600219438996090564087606.pem
                                            2019\cert-11211589658854057466031159348.pem
                                            2021\cert-11671143093416928819383653766.pem
                            baz.example.com\
                                            2019\cert-10572485377335948619489409340.pem
```

The script I have so far:

```vbnet
$path = "X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\"
$directories = Get-ChildItem $path -Directory -Recurse
foreach ($directory in $directories)
{
    if (([array]$directory.EnumerateDirectories()).count -eq 0)
    {
        #If it has no directory inside, then it's one of the folders we need to analyse
        Get-ChildItem $directory.FullName -Filter "cert*.pem" | Select-Object FullName
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this script comes along with the following constraints:

1. It shows all files from all years, whereas it should only return **the latest** (i. e. recent) **file per domain**.
2. After a full path length of 85 characters it strips the trailing characters by replacing it with three dots. This happens even if its piped to a file like `get_certificates.ps1 > cert_list.txt`

Here is an excerpt about the stripped path:

```
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\subdomain.example.com\2012\cert-1198403086374501969...
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2019\cert-1228432775295869899818124...
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2021\cert-1248208432082373470733977...
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\bar.example.com\2017\[...]
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\bar.example.com\2019\[...]
and so on [...]
```

### Expected result

From the example directory structure given above the following list with the full path and the latest (i. e. newest) file per domain (not year) is expected. Domain means `foo.example.com`, `bar.example.com` and `baz.example.com`.

So, the script should return only **one** (the recent) **file** per **domain**:

```
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2021\cert-12482084320823734707339770201.pem
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\bar.example.com\2021\cert-11671143093416928819383653766.pem
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\baz.example.com\2019\cert-10572485377335948619489409340.pem
```

### (Revised) Question

In order to make the challenge more clear let me throw the spot on one single directory, the domain `foo.example.com`. The subfolders `2014, 2016, 2019, 2020` contain outdated certificates, whereas the subfolder `2021` carries the newest and therefore valid certificate.

In total there are the following directories and files (remember, this example is restricted to the path `X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com` to ease the understanding what result should be achieved):

```
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2014\cert-10457879297372006618810300677.pem
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2016\cert-13677147326148109482722985339.pem
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2019\cert-12284327752958698998181242513.pem
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2020\cert-12335167671983512419735879508.pem
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2021\cert-12482084320823734707339770201.pem
```

The script should iterate over all directories/files in order to recognize the newest/recent certificate. Based on the five subfolders above it should return **only** the recent file including the full path as shown below:

```
X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates\foo.example.com\2021\cert-12482084320823734707339770201.pem
```

The file name including the full path is needed in order to pass the result to `openssl` for further processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question and looking at the folder structure, you only want to get the directories in the first level.
Then, use `Get-ChildItem` again to recursively get the files and select the newest one.

Try

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\Archive\SSL-Certificates' -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Filter 'cert*.pem' -File -Recurse |
     Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1).FullName
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, @Theo. Unfortunately, your suggested code returns multiple directories/files for a domain whereas it should return only one (the latest/recent one).
In order to make the needed result more clear have a look at the revised question.

Comment: @HRitter Just tested it again and... The code above returns only **one** (the newest) file per domain folder. Exactly as you asked for.  Did you try it at all? or is the folder structure different from what you show us?

Comment: As there are hundreds of subdirectories I tried it with a reduced hierarchy which gave me a missleading output. In fact, your code works perfectly. Thus, thank you one more time for your effort and patience! I mark your code as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this command inside the foreach loop:

```
gci | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | % { $_.FullName }
```

Comment: Just replacing the line

`Get-ChildItem $directory.FullName -Filter "cert*.pem" | Select-Object FullName`
   
with 

    `gci | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | % { $_.FullName }`

doesn't give any results.

So I replaced the line

    `Get-ChildItem $directory.FullName -Filter "cert*.pem" | Select-Object FullName`
   
with 

    `Get-ChildItem $directory.FullName -Filter "cert*.pem" | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | % { $_.FullName }`

which still returns multiple entries for a domain with different years.